# How can I modify registry so that svchost opens explorer.exe as the shell process?

Tags: windows-explorer, battery, svchost

When battery is running low on Windows laptops, a message saying so will appear.

[image]

Explorer.exe deals with this task, but after closing that notification it will remain in the taskbar.

[image]

Explorer.exe is called by svchost with these command line arguments: `explorer.exe /factory {ceff 45ee-c862-41 de-aee2-a022c81eda92} -Embedding` and I've found that `{ceff 45ee-c862-41 de-aee2-a022c81eda92}` CLSID is used to create another explorer instance (to show the notification) which runs as a separate process from the shell process that creates dektop and taskbar. I actually suspect that this explorer.exe instance isn't comunicating with the explorer.exe shell process and that is causing a bug.

How can I force explorer.exe to run as a shell process when it is called to show that notification? If I delete the `{ceff 45ee-c862-41 de-aee2-a022c81eda92}` CLSID key from registry, will svchost call explorer.exe without command line arguments or will svchost be unable to call explorer.exe?

PD:

I have also found the `RunAs` key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}` (which is the AppId registry location for explorer.exe) with the value `Interactive User`. That value can also be replaced with `nt authority\localservice`, `nt authority\networkservice` or `nt authority\system`. Could the problem be fixed if I replace the current value with one of those mentioned?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: But the problem is what? You don't like the taskbar entry?

Comment: The blue big notification goes away (1st picture) after I click the close button, but the explorer.exe instance remains open (see 2nd picture) until I close it manually by pressing the X. This is a Windows 10 bug that is present in all laptops

Answer (score 0):

There have been many posts written about this behavior.
It's quite possible that Microsoft intended all along for the warning
to stay around as a reminder.

I have looked at some of these posts, and the only advice that seems to
work is, in Device Manager, to disable the battery:

[image]

The battery will continue to work, but Windows will perhaps not be
monitoring it, which might cause new problems.

You may also disable the warning totally in Power Options, or postpone it,
by changing the warning thresholds under "Battery".